# Symfony2 's mongoDB returns a loggablecursor instead of my entities

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I currently use the DoctrineMongoDbBundle to make requests the my mongodb database.

Here's the call in my controller:

```
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
    $entities = $dm->getRepository('MyBundle:Animal')->findBy(array("prop" => "1")); 

    echo print_r($entities->getQuery());
    echo printf(count($entities));
    echo get_class($entities);
```

Then I tried to serialize $enitities to json and send it to the client but it didnt work.

The echos printed:

```
Array ( [prop] => 1 ) 
101
Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LoggableCursor0
```

It means that the query is correct but the count should be "2" and the type should be an Animal array.

Why is the reposity returning a LoggableCursor0 instead of an Animal array?

[edit]
How could it return an Animal array?

[edit] What would be the best way to return my result in JSON?

Answer (score 7):

Use method `toArray()`. Like this:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$entities = $dm->getRepository('MyBundle:Animal')->findBy(array("prop" => "1"))->toArray();
```

If you need to get array of entities, use `array_values()` function. Like this:

```
$entities = array_values($entities);
```

Comment: The reason for was that I used ORM in that project and have loops through entities. Now I migrated the project to ODM and don't want to deal with rewriting views :)

Comment: But you can look over Cursor, can't you?

Comment: I can, but for this I would have to rewrite views.

Comment: Maybe i don't know something but `{% foreach item in items %}` where items is Cursor should be the same as passing a result of -`>toArray()`?

Comment: You are right, for most cases it works fine, but not when the code is using index to show certain items in the view. Like this - {{images.0.title}}, {{images.3.title}}, {{images.5.title}}. If I use Cursor, then I have to use `toArray()` and make an array with `array_values()` to use indexes.

Answer (score 3):

findBy [returns](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#multiple-document-types-in-a-collection) a Cursor in MongoDB ODM unlike doctrine orm.

Try:

```
echo printf($entities->count());
```

Comment: Is there a way to get entities like ORM does? How?

Comment: @Anton: +1, Thats my question

Comment: @AntonBabenko There's no way. Though Cursor is iterable and you can build your own array of entities but in most cases you don't need to take care of it.

Comment: Thank.you for your answer. What would be the best way to return the.result in json?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc assume you're making an API, the best way would be to use [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) that supports json/xml, configuration of what properties should be serialized and serializes datetimes in a proper way.

Comment: Then you can do `$response = new Response(*json*); $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); return $response;` or better using [_format](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#book-routing-format-param) in defaults config for your routes.

Comment: @meze +1 for JMSSerialzerBundle

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bit more flexibility when storing entities as an array you can do this

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$animalLoggableCursors = $dm->getRepository('MyBundle:Animal')->findBy(array("prop" => "1"));

$animals = array()
while ($animal = $animalLoggableCursors->getNext()) {
    if ($animal->getSomeProperty() == $someValue)
        array_push($animals, $animal)
}
```