# Search Results as Dictionary or Array

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am using AFNetworking for parsing JSON output and am at a point where I am returning search results in the form of JSON. I am not sure if I should save the results as NSDictionary or NSArray? I want to show the data in a table view controller and the result set could be anywhere from 50-100 or more.

Any tips?

Here is my code:

```
if (success) {

          NSDictionary *searchResults = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"searchResults"];
              NSLog(@"%@",searchResults);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store it in whichever format it is returned. Most likely it'll be an NSArray (or an NSDictionary with exactly one entry being an NSArray - in this case you'll also want to save it as an array).

Comment: *Note*; be careful when expecting anything from JSON formatted data. Often enough the JSON rendering unit (e.g.PHP) will send you arrays that only contain a single element not as an array but as single object.

Comment: @Till that's true (+1) - but the point here is that OP should use runtime examination of the returned object to see what it actually is.

Comment: I am returning a Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LoggableCursor . Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958647/symfony2-s-mongodb-returns-a-loggablecursor-instead-of-my-entities